# Writing and reading `.rds` files using Blogdown

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, blogdown

**Context**: I have a website made with Blogdown and the Hugo-Academic theme. I work in RStudio.

**Aim:** I am trying to save a `.rds` file in one of my `.Rmd` in `content/posts`.
I would then like to refer to this file in another `.Rmd` post.

**Problem:** It all works fine (if I were working locally) until I `blogdown::serve_site()` and the site doesn't build because **when I try to save:**

```
Error in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open the connection
Calls: local ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> saveRDS -> gzfile
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, mode) :
  cannot open compressed file 'static/data/homes.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Execution halted
Error in render_page(f) :
```

**When I try to read:**

```
  Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
    Calls: local ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> readRDS -> gzfile
    Execution halted
    Error in render_page(f) :
```

I don't understand this because before `blogdown::serve_site()` the file is created and the file is read. It does exist.

**What I have done:**

For what it's worth this is the command in my `.Rmd` files.

To create the file in one post: `saveRDS(homes, file="static/data/homes.rds")`

To read the file in another post: `homes <- readRDS("static/data/homes.rds")`

Please advise. Here is my session info:

````html
``` r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] compiler_3.5.0  backports_1.1.2 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.3-2
#>  [5] tools_3.5.0     htmltools_0.3.6 yaml_2.1.19     Rcpp_0.12.19   
#>  [9] stringi_1.2.3   rmarkdown_1.10  knitr_1.20      stringr_1.3.1  
#> [13] digest_0.6.18   evaluate_0.10.1
```

Created on 2018-11-16 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).
````

Comment: I think you may want your file path to be "data/homes.rds" (unless you made a "static" subdirectory within the main "static" directory).

Comment: I know I am late with the comment. But I came here as I had the same problem. The solution can be found in (https://blogdown-demo.rbind.io/2018/02/27/r-file-paths/)